# The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library. dual boot system

Tags: linux, eclipse

My eclipse won't open, complaining about not being able to find its companion shared library. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it but it doesn't help. I think it may be because I have a dual boot system and have tried to install most things to my hard drive for windows and linux to both access. I have tried looking on similar forum posts about this issue and they don't seem to help.

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).